# Google not index my hosted-blog after adding custom domain

Tags: seo, sitemap, blogger

I started a blog 1 year ago. And my blog was appearing in Google search results.

But, some days ago, I set up a custom domain with GoDaddy and submitted my new site and a fresh sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools again.

But, now my new hosted site (`http://hugestreet.info`) is not appearing in Google search.

[image: Properties listed in Google Webmaster Tools]

Comment: What was your old domain/URL?

Comment: you can see above picture .  http://hugestreet.blogspot.com

Answer (score 2):

> some days ago

Give it time! You already have the appropriate 301 redirects set up (by Google) from the old to the new. The old URLs are still indexed. It will take time (weeks, months, ...) for Google to update its index.

The only other thing you could do, if you've not already, is to use the "change of address tool".
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106
(Although since this is a "blogspot" site ie. Google, then this might be unnecessary?)

More information:
[Move a site with URL changes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049?hl=en&ref_topic=6033084)

---

> my new hosted site (`http://hugestreet.info`) is not appearing in Google search

I've just noticed that the listed GWT property is for `www.hugestreet.info`, not `hugestreet.info`, as your URL suggests. These are two different sites in Google's eyes. If `example.com` is your site then `example.com` should be verified in GWT, not just `www.example.com`. (Both the `www` and non-www versions should be verified properties.)

Comment: should i remove my old blog url ( http://hugestreet.blogspot.com) from the google webmaster tools

Comment: No, definitely not. That **will** remove your site from Google's index! Your site is still indexed, it's just indexed under the old URL. Changing web address takes time.

Comment: 1 last question :   My 1 posts from my new hosted blog address ( http://hugestreet.info) is appearing on google search . but when , i click on the posts , then it appearing as mobile view .

Comment: That's really a very different question, but the answer is the same... give it time. I expect you are finding these pages via a `site:` search? It seems that Google has only indexed the mobile site/URL so far for some reason - perhaps more people are viewing on mobile or linking/sharing the mobile version? The mobile version has `?m=1` in the URL - remove that and you see the desktop version.

Comment: Thanks . thanks , thanks , thanks , and a lot of thanks sir .

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove your .blogspot sub domain from google, instead try to submit your custom domain name  to google. If Still google is not crawling your website then use google webmaster tool and submit sitemap then wait for few days and then resubmit, sometime because of the use of automated search engine scripts google treat the link as spam. I was having same problem for my www.youtubegb.com . After doing all this stuff i got my website indexed on google search engine.

However if Still your blog is not crawled by google then you need to manually submit website to search engine and need to ping so that google get informed about your site. Here are the two article i found that will help you to

- [Ping Sitemap to Google ,Bing ,Yahoo Yandex & Baidu Search engine](http://www.shoutingblogger.com/2013/08/Ping-Sitemap-to-Google-Bing-Yahoo-Yandex-Baidu-Search-engine.html)
- [Submit URL to Google Bing and Yahoo Search Engine for free](http://www.shoutingblogger.com/2013/08/Submit-URL-to-Google-Yahoo-and-Bing-Search-Engine-free.html)